# CentOS kernel 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 grubby fatal error

Tags: centos, kernel

The following CentOS kernel's update has failed.
After the reboot the system still loads the old and insecure kernel.

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?

```
yum history info 120                 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Transaction ID : 120
Begin time     : Wed Sep 10 21:50:21 2014
Begin rpmdb    : 397:b7b86781b6405442846d9be3ee839960f8543731
End time       :            21:51:31 2014 (70 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 397:e8473a0e85e780e40caef5d618c1f0b3d0aef842
User           : root <root>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : -y update
Transaction performed with:
        Installed     rpm-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64                         @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
    Installed     yum-3.2.29-43.el6.centos.noarch                 @updates
    Installed     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-17.el6_5.noarch @updates
Packages Altered:
    Erase   kernel-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64          @updates
    Install kernel-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64          @updates
    Updated kernel-firmware-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.noarch @updates
    Update                  2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.noarch @updates
    Updated kernel-headers-2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64  @updates
    Update                 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64  @updates
Scriptlet output:
   **1 grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template**
history info

uname -a
Linux *****.ch **2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64** #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```